# Are Chiss in Disney canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon

I'm fairly familiar with which Star Wars properties are/aren't considered Disney canon; I was thinking about it yesterday and realized that I can't think of a single appearance of the [Chiss](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chiss/Legends) race in any canonical sense, aside from Legends. Do they appear in any Disney canon works, and if so, can you point me to them?

Comment: This seems like a fair question. Don't let the downvoters get to you!

Comment: @Thunderforge thanks! I never do :D Pretty dumb question on my part though, I should really watch Rebels before asking about Disney canon

Comment: Upvoting because the negatives are undeserving imo. Just because you aren't aware of the existing works where they have already appeared doesn't make this a stupid question. Ignorance, yet knowledge.

Comment: @Allball103 - you aren't required to watch a show of a 100hour length to be allowed to ask questions, and having not watched it doesn't make you dumb in any way (for full disclosure, neither have I :)

Comment: Could we use 'Star Wars canon' instead of 'Disney canon'. Wikipedia and Wookieepedia both list 'Star Wars canon'. Disney canon would be understood as this: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Franchise/DisneyAnimatedCanon first google hit.

Comment: @Ludi it's pretty common to refer to the new Star Wars canon as Disney canon, since some people really think that calling some of the better Legends content "non-canon" makes it worthless, so they just act like Disney never acquired the rights. Is that important enough for a meta post? there's a lot of Star Wars questions on this site

Comment: I downvoted due to lack-of-research; your question is answered by the only link in your question, at 1:04

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft it's not obvious in that link though: I'd perused it relatively thoroughly and not seen anything. Now that I know I'm looking for Rebels and Thrawn it's fairly easy to spot, but that link is very crowded with Legends content.

Comment: I mean the video at the top, it's stated unambiguously at 1:04

Comment: Also the clear existence of the "Canon" tab in the linked page. Same as @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I have to downvote this question.

Comment: @Allball103 I disagree. There is only one "Canon", it is set by Lucasfilm.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes - Both Chiss (and Admiral Thrawn!) are Disney canon.

Timothy Zahn's Disney Canon novel *[Thrawn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thrawn_(novel))* introduces them.

> Eli winced. A gift for the Chiss of the stories, that would have been a deadly insult. Thrawn was behind him,  and  he  didn’t  dare  turn  around,  but  he  could  imagine the expression on that proud face.
>
> “I do, Your Majesty,” Parck said, bowing low. “**A warrior reportedly of a race known as the Chiss**.”

...

> “Would  I?”  the  Emperor  sounded  amused.  “Certainly you’re a resource of unlimited confidence. What exactly do you offer, Chiss?”

Some relevant details from new Disney canon were summarized in [Wookieepedia Chiss article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chiss).

---

As another answer noted, Thrawn (and his blue appearance) is also in *Star Wars Rebels* but I'm not aware if he's named as a Chiss there.

---

Since your question doesn't explicitly specify whether you meant Disney canon by "canon", I should for completeness's sake point out that Chiss are most certainly a part of EU Legends canon, in multiple books starting with Timothy Zahn's original trilogy.

Comment: Awesome! Haven't watched Rebels yet, thanks a ton.

Comment: (I should have clarified, but Disney canon IS canon now. So yes, that's what I meant)

Comment: @Allball103 - yeah, I mostly added that to give Valorum a reason to vent :)

Comment: EU Legends are not canon!

Comment: Adding to this, the [first appearence of Chiss](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Chiss.png) in the Disney canon was in the mobile game *Star Wars: Commander*. Another fun fact is that [the Disney chiss have pupils](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Star_Wars_Thrawn_1_Textless.jpg), wheras the Legends Chiss have [completly red eyes without pupils.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Outboundthrawn.jpg)

Comment: @KarlKastor - Reuben's answer noted that game. Give it love (upvote :)

Answer (score 18):

**Thrawn is in Star Wars Rebels, which is Disney Canon.** As we all know he is Chiss and retains the blue skin/red eye combo that we all know and... recognize?

[image: Rebels image of Thrawn]

Comment: Good answer, chose DVK's because of quotes and other examples.

Answer (score 12):

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chiss)

> The Chiss became canon when they appeared in Secret Alliances, the
>   sixth campaign featured in Star Wars: Commander, a mobile game
>   published by Disney Interactive[1](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chiss) that was released on August 21,
>   2014.

Also from [StarWars.com](https://www.starwars.com/databank/grand-admiral-thrawn) - Grand Admiral Thrawn

Thrawn was a male Chiss, with striking blue skin, red eyes, and an angular face, known for his brilliant strategic mind and ruthlessness. He was determined to “pull the rebels apart piece by piece.”

Comment: this is a good answer - if you flesh it out a bit more (ie - include some details - maybe from StarWars.com or something "official" as the canonicity of Star Wars: Commander, you may get more upvotes. You have mine because it seems this is the first new canon reference. Good catch