# What are the contradictions between Chiss in EU and Disney canons?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

[Chiss are now Disney canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167225/are-chiss-in-disney-canon).

Obviously, the EU canon has different information from Disney one on the topic.

But is any of the information between the two canon actually contradictory to each other (as opposed to merely being mentioned in one canon and not another)?

Obviously, things about "contemporary"/"future" post-Thrawn Chiss *history* that are part of EU canon but are erased by Disney's new history are out of scope, as they are contradictory by design.

Answer (score 5):

The nature of Chiss Force Sensitivity is different between the two canons, although they share the idea that the Force is very rare among the Chiss.

In Disney canon, the Chiss know the Force as the "Third Sight". They receive precognitive visions, but evidently don't have or know about any other Force talents. These seers are almost always women. No particular mention is made (that I can see) of their place in society.

In Legends canon, the Chiss see the Force as an impurity and strongly discriminate against it. Force Sensitives are exiled or given medical treatments to suppress their connection to the Force. On the other hand, those who *do* manifest powers show the full range of Force abilities that we're familiar with in other races. No mention is made of any gender preference.

There are some minor quibbles about the details of their government, but since the Chiss government in Legends is not the most stable body (having at least two, and possibly three, major configurations just during the time of the New Republic) I wouldn't count those as contradictions as such.

Comment: Do you have references for where you got this information?

Comment: @Boolean Re: Force sensitives, the canon information is primarily from the *Thrawn* novel, while the Legends is from *The Old Republic*. Re: governments, the Ascendancy was described in Legends in the Hand of Thrawn novels, and then again differently in the New Jedi Order novels (the Force Heretic trilogy to be specific), and in canon in *Thrawn* again.

Comment: (I know *The Old Republic* is a bit dated a source, but I swear that there was an earlier source about the lack of Chiss Force sensitives that was closer to the time of the movies. However, more digging is evidently needed for that.)